# Finding values from a vector in an array

Tags: arrays, r, vector, find

I have a vector called vvEq, which contains equipment numbers. And i have an array "long". Now i want to find the only rows in long which have the same equipment numbers as in vvEq. I found this code on the net, but it takes too long, i had to abort it after 1h:

```
index <- apply(long, 1, function(row) any(vvEq %in% row))
```

size of long is about 160k x 5 values.

TIA

edit: this is written in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple:

```
long[long$EquipmentNumber %in% vvEq,]
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I was lacking a proper "search" command in R, now i know it is just %in%.